# How to remove huge space (margins) around editor on wide screens in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I want the editor to take all available place, not to have unecessary white spaces there....

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Look like you are in Presentation Mode...

Comment: Thanks but no, I am not, you can see line numbers on left side and right column with projectdir (well, the screenshot is not very good at this)

Comment: I meant -- "Distraction Free mode" actually -- you can easily enable line numbers there. If I do that (with enabling extra nav bar like you have)  it will be looking similar to yours...

Comment: I have updated the screenshot to see full ide width

Comment: Oh great, I was not in Distraction free mode, but when I have entered it and then finished this, it disappeared...

Comment: So .. it must have been stucked there somehow...

Comment: Guys, thank you, it is resolved for me! (Distraction free mode). Do you think I should remove the question or give a response for others who will google like me for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in Distraction Free Mode (View -> Enter Distraction Free Mode) which I have entered accidentally.

Comment: After updating from PHPStorm 9, to PHPStorm 10, this Distraction Free Mode seemed to be enabled.
Or perhaps it was already enabled previously, but the code wasn't centre aligned before. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯